# Enter Password Alert - KeychainAccess

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm using https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess and I can't display "Enter Passcode" option in TouchID authentication prompt. It is visible on one of the images in documentation but I can't apply it in my app? Thanks

```
let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.myApp")

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    do {
        let password = try keychain
            .authenticationPrompt("Authenticate to login to server")
            .get("value")

        print("password: \(password)")
    } catch let error {
        // Error handling if needed...
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe in iOS 11 at least, it only shows "Enter Passcode" after at least one failed attempt, I could be wrong.

Comment: Exactly as you wrote, I thought there is any option to customize this prompt.